# How do I cite gggenes?

Tags: r, citations, gggenes

What's the way to properly cite gggenes for a scientific publication?

Can't find any info online about David Wilkins, the author of this package.

Comment: @Maël's answer is good, but you could also see https://wilkox.org/ or use the contact e-mail at `maintainer("gggenes")` if you wanted to double-check with the author.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `citation`:

```
citation("gggenes")

To cite package ‘gggenes’ in publications use:

  Wilkins D (2020). _gggenes: Draw Gene Arrow Maps in 'ggplot2'_.
  R package version 0.4.1,
  <https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=gggenes>.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {gggenes: Draw Gene Arrow Maps in 'ggplot2'},
    author = {David Wilkins},
    year = {2020},
    note = {R package version 0.4.1},
    url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=gggenes},
  }
```